Partioning, zorder and bloom filters in DataBricks
I'm creating tables in DataBricks and I'm looking at the best practices to add to the tables to ensure that it is response to the queries. For simplicities sake, I will only give an example of two tables.
One is the singular appointment information that is not repeated and the other is the details of the many events that can happen at that appointment.
There is a fair amount of data and to give an example there is roughly 500 million per year in the appointment table and there is 1.5 billion in the details.
The data is partition on the year. When optimising, I'm intending to run the optimise on the appointment date in the appointment table to co-locate all appointments happening on a given date which is a regular query.
In the details I'm intending to optimise on the ID column that links the two together so that all details for an appointment are co-located as it will be used in joins.
However, I'm concerned that, given some queries, this may not be enough and I'm looking into bloom filtering as well. For this I'm considering creating these on one of the specific fields where the query is often to done to find a specific detail from the field. In this case there will often be a code representing what was done so will have a large number of distinct values. I'm considering a bloom filter here as it will be on the where clause predicate which seems to be a suggestion in papers and docs I have read.
Also, how many bloom filters can be added to a table? If more then one the I'd like to add a second that is a flag in the table that I would use to the views that indicate which is the most current version of the data. In this case there is a low distinct number of values, only two in fact, as it is a Boolean true/false.
To add, I don't have formal training on DataBricks so what I'm proposing here is based solely on information that I have read in docs and on sites.
Also I don't have access to higher runtimes than DataBricks 10-4 (though I do have Photon option available). From what I've read this means that other options for liquid clustering are not available nor are deletion vectoring.
Are these good ideas or is there something else I should be considering.
Thanks very much
